# Vue/TS filter function

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I have some struggles with assigning a type to filter function with TypeScript.
So, when I'm building the app, it says like:

> Parameter 'item' implicitly has an 'any' type.

And function looks like:

```
allowedProductPaymentMethods?.filter(item => item.id !== paymentItem.id && item.balance > 0)
```

So I tried adding like `(item: any)`, but it's not recognizing the typing. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: How is `allowedProductPaymentMethods` typed?

Comment: If `allowedProductPaymentMethods: IType[]`, then it should be`.filter((item: IType) => {})

Comment: It's computed like ComputedRef<Array<IPaymentListItem>>. But even adding item: IType, it says Unresolved type IType

Comment: @HOHOOH iType was a filler. You will have to use `.filter((item: IPaymentListItem) => {})`

Answer (score 1):

if `allowedProductPaymentMethods` is computed property you should add `.value` :

```js
allowedProductPaymentMethods.value?.filter(item => item.id !== paymentItem.id && item.balance > 0)
```

Comment: but it still says that Implicity has any type :/

Comment: Please share the whole code

Answer (score 0):

If `allowedProductPaymentMethods` is typed, then, item type is inferred. [TS inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html)

If not, then you can type item inside your filter `(item: TypeYouWant)`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a linting issue and not a typescript issue.
You are able to override the compiler options in the `tsconfig.json` which should prevent this from being an issue during compilation.

The solution to your issue should be simply adding the type to your iteration variable:

```js
const allowedProductPaymentMethods: ComputedRef<Array<IPaymentListItem>>
allowedProductPaymentMethods?.filter((item: IPaymentListItem) => item.id !== paymentItem.id && item.balance > 0)
```

It does appear that you are also missing the `value` in your function when invoking the Computed object [Vue docs](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#computed):

```js
const allowedProductPaymentMethods: ComputedRef<Array<IPaymentListItem>>
allowedProductPaymentMethods?.value?.filter((item: IPaymentListItem) => item.id !== paymentItem.id && item.balance > 0)
```